# Is there a limit of max 10000 work items per Backlog?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

What does it mean the phrase "You can have up to 10000 work items on a backlog" taken from this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/service-limits?view=azure-devops#work-items ?

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises (I'll upgrade to Dev Ops Server 2019 update 1 asap) in a very large project with hundreds of users and after two years we collected more than 10000 work items in a single Team Project (10661 to be precise). I hope that I will able to add new work item in the future without limits in the same Team Project (I think it's reasonable to have a limit like 500000 or 1 million of work items but no with only 10000 work items). I'm afraid that I'll see an error message like "TFSXXXX: max number of work items reached".

I repeat: What does it mean the phrase "You can have up to 10000 work items on a backlog" taken from the above link?

[image: Total number of work items in my Team Project]

Comment: This is a limitation of Backlog, not work items. Check this link -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops#backlogs-boards-and-teams

Also, this link as well as the link you are referencing to applies for DevOps Service, not Server (on prem). So not sure if there are any similar kind of limitation for the on prem server. There is a possibility that this limitations only applies for the cloud service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the link you mentioned is about Azure devops Service, not TFS. To see the [restrictions on TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=tfs-2017), you need to switch to TFS2017 version in the upper left.

[image]

Secondly, the limitation mentioned in the document is about the maximum number of work items that can be displayed in the backlog, instead of a limit on the number of work items.

> Each backlog can **display** up to 999 work items. If your backlog exceeds
>   this limit, then you may want to consider adding a team and moving
>   some of the work items to the other team's backlog.

Regarding the limit of the number of work items, because the id of work items are increasing on a collection level, there is no limit to the increase of unique id, so the number of work items is also unlimited. You can refer to this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37abc8fd-0343-4979-a133-a4beebe18fb7/tfs-and-vsts-data-limits?forum=tfsgeneral) with similar issue.